# Active state for button loading frames

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website where I use input buttons to replace a frame.

```
<input type="button" value="NBA" class="portmenu" onclick="document.getElementById(&#39;portfolioFRAME&#39;).innerHTML=&#39;&lt;iframe src=&quot;portfolio/test3.html&quot; width=&quot;730px&quot; height=&quot;455px&quot; scrolling=&quot;yes&quot; frameborder=&quot;0px&quot;&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&#39;">
```

Everything works fine, but is there a way to leave a button highlighted after I click it to show that the frame loaded is by the button clicked?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the button to look a certain way after it's been pressed?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thepriebe/EcyVM/2/)

```
$("input.portmenu").click( function () {
    $(this).addClass("pressed");
});
```

​

Comment: Thanks! It worked great!

I have an accordian menu that expands and contracts when you click a category. Within each category <li> is the input button that I wrote above. Is there a way to make it when I click on a input button and it changes class, then I click a different button, it unselects the first button and highlights the second button?

Comment: Absolutely. You can do it like I've done in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thepriebe/EcyVM/8/).

Comment: Sorry this is so delayed, but thank you very much for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="NBA" class="portmenu" onclick=if($(this).hasClass("clicked")){$("#iframe").hide();$(this).removeClass("clicked");}else{$("#iframe").show();$(this).addClass("clicked");} >

<iframe id="iframe" style="display:none;" src="portfolio/test3.html" width="730px" height="455px" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Is this that, what did you mean? You need jQuery. It maybe work.